# Реализация функции "запомнить меня" (Remain logged in)

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

Есть сервис WCF (self-host, без IIS), обращение к нему осуществляется через интернет (https), клиент - десктопное приложение. Нужно защитить его, вход по имени пользователя и паролю. Кое-что уже реализовал, но теперь необходимо расширить это дело функцией "запомнить меня", что бы диалог входа в систему некоторое время не отображался.

Интересуют общеизвестные подходы, принципы, практики для реализации этой функции с учетом того, что клинет не веб-приложение и сервер является self-hoster-ом (Windows-Service).

Благодарю за советы.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про WCF Security Token Service. Вкратце: при логине клиенту отдается токен, клиент его запоминает и передает при последующих обращениях. Если будете сохранять токен локально на клиенте -- лучше шифруйте.

Comment: Имено так я себе это и представляю, но беспокоит, что если токен будет украден, злоумышленик сможет обращаться к сервису. Нужно наверное как-то привязываться к машине клиента.

Answer (score 0):

1. Сохранить пароль у юзера и автоматически подставлять его при попытке соединения.
2. Воспользоваться токенами.